# How to format json data to array format and nested arrays are in object like {} without square brackets in typscript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Now return data from rest api as :

```
{ 
   "ProductID":1,
   "Category":[ 
      { 
         "CategoryID":1,
         "SubCategory":[ 
            { 
               "SubCategoryID":1,

            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to converted output data manipulated in typescript as:

```
[ 
   { 
      "ProductID":1,
      "Category":{ 
         "CategoryID":1,
         "SubCategory":{ 
            "SubCategoryID":1,
            `enter code here`
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I have tried

```
return this.restApi.getProductBin().subscribe((data: {}) => {
    const usersJson: any[] = Array.of(data);
})
```

Comment: You want to flatten all nested arrays to get a plain array of objects? Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by `enter code here`?

Comment: Yes !! @Arcteezy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is the code that can convert your the format you need:

```js
const restructureProducts = (oldProds) => {
  let products = [];

  let newProd = {};
  if (oldProds.hasOwnProperty('ProductID'))
    newProd['ProductID'] = oldProds['ProductID'];

  if (
    oldProds.hasOwnProperty('Category') &&
    oldProds['Category'].length > 0 &&
    oldProds['Category'][0].hasOwnProperty('CategoryID')
  )
    newProd['Category'] = { CategoryID: oldProds['Category'][0]['CategoryID'] };
  if (oldProds['Category'][0].hasOwnProperty('SubCategory') && oldProds['Category'][0]['SubCategory'].length > 0)
    newProd['Category']['SubCategory'] = { SubCategoryID: oldProds['Category'][0]['SubCategory'][0]['SubCategoryID'] };

  products.push(newProd);
  
  return products;
}

let oldProds = {
  ProductID: 1,
  Category: [{
    CategoryID: 1,
    SubCategory: [{
      SubCategoryID: 1,
    }]
  }]
};

let products = restructureProducts(oldProds);
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Could you plz help me to make this code as method to use commonly @MEDZ

Comment: @ASP.NET Done. Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: Could you plz help me to make this code as method to use commonly not only for products ,its for all type of return data @MEDZ

Comment: I believe this is out of this question scope, plus this question was closed so I can not add further answers but you can add new question and i would be glade to answer it.

Comment: I have reached my question limit, Could you plz help me in this thread for solution to format without brackets in any data.@MEDZ

Comment: @ASP.NET see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th, this isn't an acceptable reason to hassle the people who've already put time into answering your question